# How do i set a token based on the dropdown options in splunk dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

i am trying to create a Splunk dashboard, where I want to set a value to a token based on the two dropdown values(service dropdown and environment dropdown)

```
<input type="dropdown" token="service" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>service</label>
      <choice value="capi">capi</choice>
      <choice value="crapi">crapi</choice>
      <choice value="oapi">oapi</choice>
      <default>capi</default>
      <initialValue>capi</initialValue>
  </input>
 
  <input type="dropdown" token="environment" searchWhenChanged="true">
  <label>Environment</label>
  <choice value="prod">prod</choice>
  <choice value="ppe">ppe</choice>
  <choice value="pte">pte</choice>
  <choice value="dev">dev</choice>
  <default>prod</default>
  <initialValue>prod</initialValue>
  </input>
```

above are the 2 dropdowns, now i want to set a value to token "endpoint" based on value selected in service and environment dropdown values.

i tried using condition match, but i am not getting it right

```
<condition match="$service$==capi AND $environment$==ppe">
<set token = endpoint>"/capi/ppe"</set>
</condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an `eval` in your search proper:

```
<search>
  <query>... | eval endpoint="/$service$/$environment$" | ...
```

Or try doing an `<eval>...</eval>` on [change](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML#eval.2C_link.2C_set.2C_and_unset) from both dropdowns:

```
<input type="dropdown" token="service" searchWhenChanged="true">
  <label>service</label>
  <choice value="capi">capi</choice>
  <choice value="crapi">crapi</choice>
  <choice value="oapi">oapi</choice>
  <default>capi</default>
  <initialValue>capi</initialValue>
  <change>
    <eval token="endpoint">"/"+$service$+"/"+$environment$</eval>
  </change>
</input>

<input type="dropdown" token="environment" searchWhenChanged="true">
  <label>Environment</label>
  <choice value="prod">prod</choice>
  <choice value="ppe">ppe</choice>
  <choice value="pte">pte</choice>
  <choice value="dev">dev</choice>
  <default>prod</default>
  <initialValue>prod</initialValue>
  <change>
    <eval token="endpoint">"/"+$service$+"/"+$environment$</eval>
  </change>    
</input>
```